# pymysql - name of default cursorclass

Tags: python, pymysql

This is probably a stupid question but I cannot find the information in the documentation for pymysql. What is the pymysql default cursorclass? When I do not specify a cursor class on connection to the database my queries return a list for each row in the response.

When I specify pymysql.cursors.DictCursor I get a dictionary response. I would like to be able to change between them for different connections within a script.

I've written a little function with a context manager to yield the cursor but it requires me to specify the name of the cursorclass each time. I know I can get around this, but knowing the name of the default cursorclass would be nice.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import pymysql

@contextmanager                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
def openDb(host=DB_HOST, database=DB_DATABASE,                                                                                                                                                                                     
           user=DB_USER, cursor=DB_CURSOR):                                                                                                                                                                                        
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Simple context manager for opening a db connection                                                                                                                                                                                        
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    with pymysql.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user,                                                                                                                                                                             
                         cursorclass=cursor) as cur:                                                                                                                                                                                          
        yield cur
```

I could probably write this as:

```
@contextmanager                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
def openDb(host=DB_HOST, database=DB_DATABASE,                                                                                                                                                                                     
           user=DB_USER, cursor=None):                                                                                                                                                                                        
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Simple context manager for opening a db connection                                                                                                                                                                                        
    """
    if cursor:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        with pymysql.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user,                                                                                                                                                                             
                             cursorclass=cursor) as cur:                                                                                                                                                                                          
            yield cur
    else:
        with pymysql.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user) as cur:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            yield cur
```

and let it default to whatever the default cursorclass is, but I would prefer to be explicit.

Comment: It looks like it's `pymysql.cursors.Cursor`, but it's hard to tell. The only documentation I found sucks. You could try introspecting `pymysql.connect` with something like [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) to look at the default argument values.

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I posted this it occurred to me to look in the docstrings. If it is in the docstrings I have no idea why there is not a complete API reference on the RTDs page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course as soon as I post this I find the answer in via:

```
>>> import pymysql                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> help(pymysql.cursors)

Help on module pymysql.cursors in pymysql:

NAME
    pymysql.cursors - # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

CLASSES
    builtins.object
        Cursor
            SSCursor
        DictCursorMixin
            DictCursor(DictCursorMixin, Cursor)
            SSDictCursor(DictCursorMixin, SSCursor)
```

`pymysql.cursors.Cursor` is the answer. Documentation...